# How do I validate cells when using a custom cell editor in DevExpress DXGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a DXGrid, I have a column defined like this

```
       <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="InvType.TypeName" Validate="TypeName_OnValidate" >
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="PART_Editor" AutoComplete="True"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.InvTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=dxg:GridControl}}"
                                          DisplayMember="TypeName" Validate="BaseEdit_OnValidate"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Each row displays an instance of InvType, and the grid does not allow editing in this column, unless it's the new row item.

In short I want cells to show a ComboBoxEdit when they are being edited, and then handle the GridColumn Validate event.

The problem is that the Validate event on the GridColumn does not fire. The Validate event on the ComboBoxEdit does fire, but this only provides a ValidationEventArgs, instead of the GridCellValidationEventArgs that I need.

Is there any way to have the combobox when editing and also have the GridColumn event fire correctly?

Edit:
I solved this by using EditSettings instead of a ContentControl.

```
      <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="InvType.TypeName" Validate="TypeName_OnValidate">
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings AutoComplete="True"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.InvTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=dxg:GridControl}}"
                                          DisplayMember="TypeName" ValueMember="TypeName"/>
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar work.
Essentially, you can create a utility class with validations attached property (which takes your datacolumn , and attaches handler to Validate event).

The usage goes like this:

```
<Grid:GridColumn  x:Name="EventEndTimeColumn"
Header="Time" Width="40" AllowEditing="True" EditSettings="{dxe:TextSettings HorizontalContentAlignment=Center}" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center">
   <Validator:GridColumnValidationRulesHelper.ValidationRules>
      <Validator:GridColumnValidationRules>
           <Validator:CustomValidationRule  ErrorMessage="Invalid Value"/>
      </Validator:GridColumnValidationRules>
   </Validator:GridColumnValidationRulesHelper.ValidationRules>
```

You can get the validation helper code in my [blog](http://www.devdumps.com/2014/05/24/column-value-validation-in-dev-express-grid-2/).